# On which page of the Player's Handbook are the rules for object interactions located?

Tags: dnd-5e, objects, action-economy

On which page of the Player's Handbook are the rules for object interactions located ? I mean the whole "one free object interaction" thing ? Where is it stated ??

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't find it? Where have you expected to find it and then not?

Comment: @Someone_Evil This is a "read for me the book" question, isn't it? What are the guidance in such cases?

Comment: @Eddymage There's [What Do We Do With "Read The Book To Me" Questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270), and possibly more specific: [Is asking a question about the location (pg number, chapter, etc) of content in a specific book on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6585). And there's the general guidance that a question showing lack of research is a downvote reason (and that's part of the downvote button tooltip).

Comment: @Someone_Evil I completely missed the second meta you linked, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for "Other Activity on Your Turn" on page 190 of the  *Player's Handbook* and page 73 of the *Basic Rules* pdf:

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the
> environment for free, during either your move or your
> action. For example, you could open a door during your
> move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your
> weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.

This section has below it a table of example object interactions (unfortunately placed below the Movement and Position header).

Additionally, the "Use an Object" action is described on page 193 (pg. 75 of *BR*):

> You normally interact with an object while doing
> something else, such as when you draw a sword as part
> of an attack. When an object requires your action for
> its use, you take the Use an Object action. This action
> is also useful when you want to interact with more than
> one object on your turn.

Answer (score -3):

the *Use and Object* action is described briefly in the PHB, page 193.

It describes the action as "When an object requires your action for its use, you take the *Use an Object* action" and assumes that using an object is usually part of another action, like attacking with a sword or casting as spell with a components pouch.

Specific rules for each item will be described on the item entry.

However, this counts as an Action unless otherwise stated.